# Why doesn't npx react-native init MyApp not work and doesn't create a React Native project?

Tags: javascript, react-native, babeljs, npx, babel-jest

I'm trying to start an App with `npx react-native init <MyApp>` but it doesn't finish building.
Two days ago this worked and today it doesn't.
I've googled for ideas, but I don't see anything like it

After a while building and downloading dependencies, everything stops and the console shows the following

The iOS and Android folders are not quite complete, and when I try to run iOS or Android I get errors.

Searching I found articles related to `ignore-engines`, but I don't understand why this happens to me suddenly, when 2 days ago everything was working

What does this error mean and why?
Thank you

> error jest-cli@28.0.2: The engine "node" is incompatible with this
> module. Expected version "^12.13.0 || ^14.15.0 || ^16.10.0 ||
>
> > =17.0.0". Got "16.6.0" error Found incompatible module. info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this
> > command. /Volumes/MIguelApps/REACT-NATIVE/pruebas/carpeta sin
> > título/Senderos/node_modules/metro-hermes-compiler/src/emhermesc.js:77
> > throw ex;
> > ^
>
> RuntimeError: abort(Error: Command failed: yarn add -D @babel/core
> @babel/runtime @react-native-community/eslint-config eslint jest
> babel-jest metro-react-native-babel-preset
> react-test-renderer@17.0.2). Build with -s ASSERTIONS=1 for more info.
> at process.abort (/Volumes/MIguelApps/REACT-NATIVE/pruebas/carpeta sin
> título/Senderos/node_modules/metro-hermes-compiler/src/emhermesc.js:402:15)
> at process.emit (node:events:394:28)
> at emit (node:internal/process/promises:136:22)
> at processPromiseRejections (node:internal/process/promises:242:25)
> at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:97:32)
>
> /////////////////////////
>
> warning Pattern ["@babel/core@^7.17.9"] is trying to unpack in the
> same destination
> "/Users/miguelito/Library/Caches/Yarn/v6/npm-@babel-core-7.17.9-6bae81a06d95f4d0dec5bb9d74bbc1f58babdcfe-integrity/node_modules/@babel/core"
> as pattern
> ["@babel/core@^7.14.0","@babel/core@^7.14.0","@babel/core@^7.14.0","@babel/core@^7.13.16","@babel/core@^7.14.0","@babel/core@^7.14.0","@babel/core@^7.14.0","@babel/core@^7.11.6","@babel/core@^7.11.6","@babel/core@^7.12.3","@babel/core@^7.11.6","@babel/core@^7.14.0"].
> This could result in non-deterministic behavior, skipping. warning
> Pattern ["@babel/runtime@^7.17.9"] is trying to unpack in the same
> destination
> "/Users/miguelito/Library/Caches/Yarn/v6/npm-@babel-runtime-7.17.9-d19fbf802d01a8cb6cf053a64e472d42c434ba72-integrity/node_modules/@babel/runtime"
> as pattern ["@babel/runtime@^7.8.4"]. This could result in
> non-deterministic behavior, skipping.

Comment: Do you try to update your node version?

Comment: No, I just wanted to build a new project and it won't finish building. 3 days ago everything was working fine, I don't understand what's going on today. And I don't know what the error is. My version of Node is 16.6.0

Comment: You are trying to install  jest-cli@28.0.2 and this package require node version ^16.10.0

Comment: I don't want to install anything, I just want to build a new project with `npx react-native init MYAPP` and I get this error. Two days ago this did not happen. What do you suggest me, to upgrade Node or downgrade Node? But do you know why this happens?

Comment: If you want to use react native 0.68 I recommend you upgrade Node to the last LTS.

Answer (score 0):

had same issue and upgrading to latest node worked for me.